# Python + Gtk: File dialog when closed, how to check?

Tags: python, pygtk, openfiledialog

In my code I use an open Gtk file dialog first. After a file has been chosen, a list of all open windows is obtained, which I realize with the help of Gtk.

The point is that in my current code (see code below), the window of the open-file dialog is also mentioned (last in the list), although it should be closed and therefore non-existent. Even if I put in a 'sleep(5)' after the dialog routine, the dialog window is in the list of windows. Strange is that the dialog window is frozen within the 5 seconds, it should be closed! How can I avoid that the dialog window is in the list? Or is there any means to check if the window is non-existent, something like a wait_for_closed_window routine?

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Wnck
from time import sleep

def open_dialog_load_file():

    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open ...", None,
                                   Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                                   (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                                   Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

    response = dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        session_file = dialog.get_filename()
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        session_file = ""
    dialog.destroy()
    print session_file

    return session_file


if __name__ == '__main__':    

    open_dialog_load_file()

    sleep(2)

    Gtk.init([])
    screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
    screen.force_update()
    list_wnds = screen.get_windows()
    screen = None
    Wnck.shutdown()

    print
    for wnd in list_wnds: 
        print "        " + wnd.get_name()
    print
```

Comment: I've opened another question which is related to this one. It is asking about how to check for shown dialogs. They're not windows, so they don't show up in the window list you are getting with `screen.get_windows()`, but I cannot tell you how you actually get a handle on the dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following after `screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()`

```
while Gtk.events_pending():
    Gtk.main_iteration()
```

no need for `sleep`